# Want to get an SHP file for my coutry Algeria

Tags: shapefile, data, r, cartography

H everyone , i'm running a clustering test on my country with R, but the problem the clustering doen't look good because of the map i have, i hant to get a bigger map of my country 'ALGERIA' in an SHP format!

Can you suggest links or Ideas of how can i get the Map of my coutry in a big format ?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with your shape? What do you mean/consider as "big"? Detailed? Have a look at http://naturalearthdata.com/ and http://www.gadm.org/ I also don't see the relevance of your question for other users...

Comment: because i run a clustering test on the map, you can see how it's looking on this link http://selmane.comli.com/a/  ! the regions here does not look very well! i have tried your website, and i'm looking at what they have thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use OpenStreetMap data. Global land and water polygons are freely available from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons, a service offered by Jochen Topf.
You can also check http://www.gadm.org/country and choose Algeria from the list.